# Building cmake static library

Tags: cmake

I have a project (static library) say of this form:

```
rootlib/
  CMakeLists.txt     (1)
  src1.c
  sublib1/
    CMakeLists.txt   (2)
    subsrc1.c
  sublib2/
    CMakeLists.txt   (3)
    subsrc2.c
```

- In all `CMakeLists.txt` I do `add_library(... sources)`
- In (1) I also do `target_link_libraries(rootlib sublib1 sublib2)`

After `make`, I have three `*.a` files that are nowhere merged together. All I want to do now, is to create (automatically) a static library (i.e. merge everything).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use Cmake 2.8.8 with new feature - object library: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library

Or write by yourself via add_custom_target